# Kohanic in vitro Pregnancy

Tags: marriage, kohen-priest, science, pregnancy-birth

I have the following theoretical questions, from many I’ve met and even a real case of someone very special I met in a hostel in Israel.

My assumptions are between parentheses after the list item.

What’s the status of the following children, with a Kohen father, just the status per item and sources as links so the answers aren’t unreadeable.

1- In vitro, permitted jewish egg, non-jewish uterus. (not jewish)

2- In vitro, non-jewish egg, permitted jewish uterus. (Jewish but chalal?)

3- In vitro, forbidden jewish egg, transplanted to permitted jewish uterus. (Probably not jewish or chalal?)

4- In vitro, permitted jewish egg, transplanted to forbidden jewish uterus. (Chalal)

5- In vitro, a mamzera egg transferred to a permitted jewish uterus (big question).

6- In vitro, a permitted jewish egg, transferred to a mamzerah.

7- Regular intercourse, prohibited jewish female, fetus transplanted to permitted jewish uterus.

8- Regular intercourse, permitted jewish female, fetus transplanted to prohibited jewish uterus.

9- Regular intercourse, non jewish female, fetus transplanted to jewish female.

10- Regular intercourse, prohibited jewish female, fetus transplanted to permitted jewish female.

Comment: Is fetus transplantation possible?

Comment: This shuir might help you https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/939736/rabbi-dani-schreiber/discussing-judaisms-biggest-questions-whos-your-daddy-fertility-technology-in-halacha/ he goes through talking about IVF when the child becomes the fathers

Comment: DoubleAA, yes. I actually met a Cohen who had such situation. Not sure if he meant something else but he spelled fetus.

Comment: From this fellow in a hostel, yes.

Comment: עיין שו"ת מנחת שלמה תנינא סימן קכד